# Timeout запроса при парсинге PHP Simple Parser DOM

Tags: php, парсер

Стоит задача запросить контент страницы и записать в кэш. Если сайт не доступен, то читать из кэша. Не могу найти способ для этой библиотеки парсинга. Может кто подскажет решение? Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
$ctx = stream_context_create(array('http'=>
   array(
     'timeout' => 15,  //таймаут запроса сайту
   )
));

$data=file_get_contents('http://ya.ru', false, $ctx);
    if($data) {
        $html = str_get_html($data); 
        $ret = $html->find('div'); 
    }
```